# Infinite summation convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence of positive terms. If $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a_n \cdot a_{n+1}}$ converges, does $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$?

I know that if any series of positive terms converges, a new series formed by squaring each term also converges. So $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \cdot a_{n+1} $ converges in this case. Not sure how to prove or disprove the above from here.

Comment: Yes, but how to proceed? Say each term is <= $max(a_n,a_{n+1})$, which in turn is <= $a_n + a_{n+1}$. But that doesnt tell me if the sequence converges. The square root is an upper bound for $min$, but $min(a_n, a_{n+1})$ convergence doesnt imply the series itself converges

Comment: @charMD: that proves the opposite: if $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a positive sequence and $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$ converges, so does $\sum_{n\geq 1}\sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}}$, since $\sqrt{a_n\cdot a_{n+1}}\leq \frac{a_n+a_{n+1}}{2}$ by AM-GM.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I had misread the question, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $a_n = \begin{cases} \frac{2}{n}&\text{if}~n~\text{is even}\\ \frac{1}{(n+1)^5}&\text{if}~n~\text{is odd}\end{cases}$

We have $\sqrt{a_n\cdot a_{n+1}}$ acts very similarly to $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n^3}$ and the series $\sum \sqrt{a_n\cdot a_{n+1}}$ will indeed converge.

However, $\sum a_n$ contains the harmonic sum and therefore diverges.

---

Another:

Consider $a_n = \begin{cases} n&\text{if}~n~\text{is even}\\ \frac{1}{(n+1)^7}&\text{if}~n~\text{is odd}\end{cases}$

Similarly to the earlier counterexample, we have $b_n=\sqrt{a_n\cdot a_{n+1}}$ acts like $\frac{1}{n^3}$ and so $\sum \sqrt{a_n\cdot a_{n+1}}$ converges however $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq 0$ and so $\sum a_n$ diverges by the basic divergence test.

Comment: You can try to clean it up a little bit if you like.  Using my style of counterexample, it seems that at least somewhere there will be some mess to deal with.  To prove that $\sum\sqrt{a_n\cdot a_{n+1}}$ converges more formally, define $b_n = \sqrt{a_n\cdot a_{n+1}}$ and write it out explicitly for if $n$ is even or $n$ is odd.  Comparison tests to $\frac{1}{n^3}$ or similarly ordered sequences should do the trick.